# Unexpected keyword arg in decorator : Python

Tags: python, eclipse, decorator

I have a problem with eclipse and my python decorator. 
I use a decorator to manage communication error automatically. 
When I use the decorator, by default, the decorator will get the error of the decorated function, and if it is not OK, raise an exception.

```
def error_handling_decor_2(function):

    @wraps(function)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):

        catch_error = kwargs.get('catch_error', True)
        kwargs.pop('catch_error', None)

        (ret_val, error_val) = function(*args, **kwargs)

        if catch_error:
            if error_val == 'OK':
                return ret_val
            else:
                raise Exception('Problem')
        else:
            # return without any processing
            return ret_val, error_val

    return wrapper
```

So if I want the decorated function to return a tuple with `(ret_val, error)`, I have to pass as parameter: `catch_error=False`.

Everything is working correctly, the only problem is that eclipse show an error on the editor: `Passing unexpected keyword argument 'catch_error' in function call`.

That is right, the method call does not have argument `catch_error` but the decorator does handle it.

Does anyone have an idea to avoid seeing this error?

Comment: So you see the warning on a line that calls the decorated function?

Comment: How do you call the decorator?

Comment: The warning comes from PyLint. See the duplicate on how to disable the warning.

Comment: I call it like that :  @error_handling_decor_2
                            def get_accum_debt(self):

Comment: (dupe target updated to a better post)

Comment: Add `# pylint: disable=E1123` to the line that calls your decorated function.

Comment: Should I disable the warning in Pylint, there is no way to do it properly?

Comment: You know that you can compress those two lines in a single call: `catch_error = kwargs.pop('catch_error', True)`, don't you?

Comment: Not in Python 2, you can't use `*args` and `**kwargs` *and* declare the `catch_error` argument in the wrapper signature.

Comment: Good to know for the kwargs.pop, by the way, I am using python 2.7